# How to drop NaN elements in a groupby on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this dataframe :

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,np.nan,'gate','ball'],'B':['car',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[np.nan,'edge',np.nan,np.nan],'D':['id1','id1','id1','id2']})

In [176]: my_df
Out[176]:
  A    B     C    D
0   NaN  car   NaN  id1
1   NaN  NaN  edge  id1
2  gate  NaN   NaN  id1
3  ball  NaN   NaN  id2
```

I want to group by column `D` and to ignore the `NaN`. Expected output :

```
        A    B     C
D
id1  gate  car  edge
id2  ball  NaN  NaN
```

My solution would be to fill `NaN` with empty char and to take the `max`:

```
In [177]: my_df.fillna("").groupby("D").max()
Out[177]:
    A    B     C
D
id1  gate  car  edge
id2  ball
```

Is there another solution without `fillna("")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use custom function with `dropna`, but for empty values add `NaN`s:

```
print (my_df.groupby("D").agg(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().all() else x.dropna()))
        A    B     C
D                   
id1  gate  car  edge
id2  ball  NaN   NaN
```

Similar solution with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    y = x.dropna()
    return np.nan if y.empty else y

print (my_df.groupby("D").agg(f))
        A    B     C
D                   
id1  gate  car  edge
id2  ball  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks that's great !!

Comment: I thought there was no answer. SO didn't update the page. Answer already accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is much better I guess but add a replace at the end

```
my_df.fillna("").groupby("D").max().replace('',np.nan)
```

You can also do :

```
def get_notnull(x):
    if x.notnull().any():
        return  x[x.notnull()]
    else:
        return np.nan

my_df.groupby('D').agg(get_notnull)
```

Output :

```
     A    B     C
D                   
id1  gate  car  edge
id2  ball  NaN   NaN
```