# How to add NaN elements in a groupby on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data:

```
    id                 time           w
0   39  2018-03-01 00:00:00 1176.000000
1   39  2018-03-01 01:45:00 1033.461538
2   39  2018-03-01 02:00:00 1081.066667
3   39  2018-03-01 02:15:00 1067.909091
4   39  2018-03-01 02:30:00 1026.600000
5   39  2018-03-01 02:45:00 1051.866667
```

I have groupby once every fifteen minutes from the original data.

But I want to present:

```
    id                 time           w
0   39  2018-03-01 00:00:00 1176.000000
1   39  2018-03-01 00:15:00     NaN
2   39  2018-03-01 00:30:00     NaN
.   39      ...      ...        ...
.   39      ...      ...        ...
.   39  2018-03-01 01:30:00     NaN
1   39  2018-03-01 01:45:00 1033.461538
2   39  2018-03-01 02:00:00 1081.066667
3   39  2018-03-01 02:15:00 1067.909091
4   39  2018-03-01 02:30:00 1026.600000
5   39  2018-03-01 02:45:00 1051.866667
```

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376077/how-to-drop-nan-elements-in-a-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe) but it was not work.

Like this:

```
showData = Data.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='15T')])
['w'].mean().replace('',np.nan).reset_index()
```

I really need your help.Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `resample`:

```
df.resample('15min', on='time').mean()

                       id            w
time                                  
2018-03-01 00:00:00  39.0  1176.000000
2018-03-01 00:15:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 00:30:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 00:45:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 01:00:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 01:15:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 01:30:00   NaN          NaN
2018-03-01 01:45:00  39.0  1033.461538
2018-03-01 02:00:00  39.0  1081.066667
2018-03-01 02:15:00  39.0  1067.909091
2018-03-01 02:30:00  39.0  1026.600000
2018-03-01 02:45:00  39.0  1051.866667
```

To fill in you `id`, you can just use `fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
resampled_df = df.resample('15T', on='time').mean()

resampled_df['id'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

resampled_df

                       id            w
time                                  
2018-03-01 00:00:00  39.0  1176.000000
2018-03-01 00:15:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 00:30:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 00:45:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 01:00:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 01:15:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 01:30:00  39.0          NaN
2018-03-01 01:45:00  39.0  1033.461538
2018-03-01 02:00:00  39.0  1081.066667
2018-03-01 02:15:00  39.0  1067.909091
2018-03-01 02:30:00  39.0  1026.600000
2018-03-01 02:45:00  39.0  1051.866667
```